# iOS: Running profiles on Backdate

Tags: iphone, ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I am sorry this question is not directly related to programming.

My Distribution profile getting expired on November,5th. For some credit card reasons I am not able to renew it for a while. Question is, can I run my system on back date to keep my profile active so that I can make distribution builds of AdHoc Profiles for testing on client's device?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, if and only if you have built the app before the expiry date.

Comment: You won't be able to build a new app in release mode after expiry of provisioning

Comment: Fortunately i had also created a developer profile for client's device. Can I use that for Adhoc builds?